# Overfull \hbox too wide in table

Tags: tables

I have the following table

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}


\begin{document}
\section{Results}
\label{Sec:results}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%       Table          %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \begin{table}[tb]
    \centering  
    \tabcolsep = 0.01\textwidth %0.18cm
    \begin{tabular}{| m{0.17\textwidth} | M{0.1\textwidth} | M{0.1\textwidth}|}
    \hline
     \centering\textbf{Method} & \textbf{Input} & \textbf{Accuracy}
     \tabularnewline
    \hline
        3DShapeNets  & volumetric & 84.7\\
        Voxnet  & volumetric & 85.9\\
    \hline
        PointNet  & points & 89.2 \\
        PointNet++  & points & 90.7 \\
        Kd-network& points & 91.8 / 90.6 \\
    \hline
    Ours & points & ? \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Classification Accuracy on ModelNet40 dataset}
    \label{table:ClassificationAcc}
\end{table}

    \begin{table}[tb]
    \centering  
    \tabcolsep = 0.01\textwidth %0.18cm
    \begin{tabular}{|m{0.12\textwidth}|M{0.1\textwidth}|M{0.15\textwidth}|M{0.08\textwidth}|}
    \hline
    \centering\textbf{Method} &  \textbf{ Data} & \textbf{Permutations} & \textbf{Points}  
     \tabularnewline
    \hline
        PointNet &  & &\\
        PointNet++ &  &  &\\
        Kd-Network &  & &\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Challenges summary }
    \label{table:ChallangeComp}
\end{table}


    \subsection{Architecture Design Analysis}
    \label{SubSec:Arch_Dn_Analysis}

    \subsection{Visualizations}
    \label{SubSec:Vis}

\end{document}
```

I get a warning `Overfull \hbox (... too wide)` ... 
Why is this happening and how can I solve it ?

Comment: Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of code snippets. How are we supposed to know how you defined the column type `M`?

Comment: if i change`M` to `m`, i cant reproduce your problem. without knowing your document preamble is not possible to help you. consider above comment.

Comment: In a standard document that table does not produce an overfull box. If I however do `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}` then I do get an overfull warning, as the table is wider than a single column. And the solution is then obvious: make the columns of the table narrower. But it's not really clear what your setup is, so please elaborate.

Comment: In general "overfull \hbox" means that a content of a `\hbox` is too wide for the box. You can solve it by either reducing the stuff inside the box in question, or by increasing the box's size.

Comment: I edited to have a minimal working example ( sorry)

Comment: Why adding `\centering` in centered cells ?

Comment: @SalimBou no good reason (I am  new to TeX). but removing it did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Skillmon How do I know which box is causing the problem ?  and how do I increase the box size? (given that the text inside the box must remain as is)

Comment: Usually you get the box by reading the warning, which states on which lines the overfull box was. If you're 100% sure, that everything is fine and want to silence the warning, put a `\makebox[0pt]{}` around the offending code (this doesn't increase the size of the box but tells TeX the contents are of width 0pt). In case the overfull box was in a table, increase the column width, etc. There is no standard way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problematic is your second table. it is wider than column width. it is possible to make it narrower, however content of table is unknown, so the obtained result probably in real document will not works.

[image]

as you can see, i change table layout. for my taste now looks better. for this i add two new packages: `booktabs` for rules and `siunitx` for `S` column type. i also assume that content of column header is the widest cells contents.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries}c}{#1}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \section{Results}
    \label{Sec:results}
\lipsum[22]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%       Table
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{l l S[table-format=2.1]}
    \toprule
\mc{Method} & \mc{Input}    & \mc{Accuracy} \\
    \midrule
3DShapeNets & volumetric    & 84.7          \\
Voxnet      & volumetric    & 85.9          \\
    \midrule
PointNet    & points        & 89.2          \\
PointNet++  & points        & 90.7          \\
Kd-network  & points        & {91.8 / 90.6} \\
    \midrule
Ours        & points        & {?}           \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Classification Accuracy on ModelNet40 dataset}
    \label{table:ClassificationAcc}
\end{table}
\lipsum[44]
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{ l l l l}
    \toprule
\mc{Method} & \mc{Data}     & \mc{Permutations} & \mc{Points}   \\
    \midrule
PointNet    &               &                   &               \\
PointNet++  &               &                   &               \\
Kd-Network  &               &                   &               \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Challenges summary }
    \label{table:ChallangeComp}
\end{table}
\lipsum

    \subsection{Architecture Design Analysis}
    \label{SubSec:Arch_Dn_Analysis}

    \subsection{Visualizations}
    \label{SubSec:Vis}
\end{document}
```

above *mwe* gives no error, no warning, no bad boxes.

Comment: WOW. Thanks. I was hoping for something simpler. In addition, I am not sure yet if the content of the column header is the widest. Maybe my best option is to make this table go across the two columns.